# Convert text to number in VBA Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Doesn't

`Worksheets("Data").Cells(9, 17) + 0#` in VBA code convert "6" (or any number stored as text) automatically to number?

If not, do you know of any manner to do the trick? Thank you!

Comment: AS far as I can tell, your method will result in a double for any number stored as text. You can also omit the #. VBA will also treat the value as a double by simply treating it as a number. `Dim x as double    x = Worksheets("Data").Cells(9,17)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the string as a Dboule data type if you need to use it within your code:

```
Dim dbl As Double
dbl = CDbl(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").cells(9, 17))
```

Comment: Cdbl is not needed as VBA will do this implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Worksheets("Data").Cells(9,17).NumberFormat = "0"`.

Comment: This does not work. The value isn't changed by the NumberFormat. So a number stored as text is still text.

Comment: This changes the format of a cell from text to number on a test spreadsheet I made.  It seems from your comment on the original post that you infered he wanted it as a double.  You could just chang "0" to "0.00" to have the value formated as a double number cell.

Comment: No... double is the default number type used in VBA when you obtain a number from an Excel cell. All I'm saying is changing the format, will not change the datatype returned by `Cell.Value`.